# How to across the authentication invoke clicks or make changes on a Web site with the automation script within a browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I need to click on specified links on my profile on the website automatically with the script. I tried to use Selenium and Python for this purpose, but unfortunately, the Web site detects a frequent login and may block my profile in this case.
How to automate the site serving process with the script (javascript, node.js, etc), across the authentication and  click or make some changes on a Web site protected by login?

Answer (score 1):

Can you stay logged in with scrapy session?